# Using only Linq or Lambda, how do I combine both pieces of code to return List<Entity> e?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-5

This code works but it's super slow. I'm using the Entity Framework 5.0. So, Using only Linq or Lambda, how do I combine both pieces of code to return `List<Entity> e`?

```
CMSEntities c = new CMSEntities();

var p = c.Entities.Where(
    x => x.Address != null
    && x.Address.AddressType != null
    && x.Address.AddressType.AddressTypeID == 1
    && x.Tags.FirstOrDefault() != null)
    .ToList();

List<Entity> e = new List<Entity>();

foreach (var a in p)
{
    var d = a.Tags.Where(y => y.Feature.FeatureID == 39).FirstOrDefault();

    if (d != null)
    {
        e.Add(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var e = c.Entities.Where(
                         x => x.Address != null
                           && x.Address.AddressType != null
                           && x.Address.AddressType.AddressTypeID == 1
                           && x.Tags.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Feature.FeatureID == 39) != null
                        ).ToList();
```

You can directly do it in one query. But I don't know if its going to make big speed difference.

As per Jon's suggestion in comments, this reads better by using `Any` instead of `FirstOrDefault`. Like:

```
var e = c.Entities.Where(
                         x => x.Address != null
                           && x.Address.AddressType != null
                           && x.Address.AddressType.AddressTypeID == 1
                           && x.Tags.Any(y => y.Feature.FeatureID == 39)
                        ).ToList();
```

Comment: I'd use `Tags.Any(...)` rather than using `FirstOrDefault` here.

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of the .ToList() call, and the performance should improve significantly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the "null" checks are unnecessary but without looking at your EDM/DataModel this is pure speculation.

```
var e = c.Entities.Where(
                     x => x.Address.AddressType.AddressTypeID == 1
                       && x.Tags.Any(y => y.Feature.FeatureID == 39)
                    );
 foreach (var a in p)
        {
            var d = a.Tags.Where(y => y.Feature.FeatureID == 39).FirstOrDefault();

            if (d != null)
            {
                e.Add(a);
            }
        }
```